# Xamarin Android to edit axml. where to switch Design/Code?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, designer, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to make Android app with VS2012+Xamarin.
As a WPF programmer, I usually toggle Design/Code with F7/Ctrl+F7 during XAML editing.

However, I cannot find in axml editting. (I use 'Open With...' to call XML editor).
I found Xamarin Studio has this button at the bottom left corner of the editor.

Does Xamarin+VS miss this feature? or is there any keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there's no formal link between a layout file (the .axml file) and an Android Activity class, there's no real way for it to know what you'd want to switch to/from.

A single Activity might use more than one layout file or a single layout file might be used by more than one Activity.

I usually just arrange the tabs so that the layout file and Activity class are next to each other.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my asking is switching between axml WYSIWYG view and its code. not Activity and axml.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old one, but if you "Open With" the .axml file with

- Automatic Editor Selector (XML)
- Or via Resharper CNTL-T

there is a chance it will just open in XML view with no obvious way to get to Design mode.

If you "Open With" -

- Android Designer (probably then Set As Default)

Then opening the file from VS (2015 at time of writing) will open in design mode and you can switch back and forth.